# Is there any point to playing Lineage II casually?

Tags: lineage-2

Since it's the only MMORPG I ever found appealing, I'm considering playing Lineage II a bit. However, in many MMORPGs, sooner or later there comes a time when you can do nothing as an individual, since everything is aimed at larger groups; and I'm not willing to coordinate my already schedule with a bunch of strange people.

Is there enough content for me, as a single player?
If not, how many teammates would I need to actually enjoy playing?

Comment: Speaking in more general terms, the focus on solo-able content is a relatively new concept.  Even in vanilla WoW there was very little outside of PvP to do that didn't require a group.  If you want an MMO with more to do as an individual, you probably want to look at more recent releases.  Games like DC Universe Online, Star Wars: The Old Republic (I played the beta, game doesn't come out for a couple of weeks) and Rift are more recent releases where considerably more development effort went into solo content than games release 5+ years ago.

Comment: I am not sure I can agree with you @zeonic. Most early MMO games did not concentrate exclusively on large parties or group-heavy gameplay, since they originated straightly from single-player RPGs (Diablo, Ultima series) and MUDs. These games (i.e. Ultima Online, EverQuest, Asheron's Call) did not have that many large scale team-based features, such as boss raids, instance dungeons, castle sieges, clan wars etc. - these appeared and were developed with more recent games, with World of Warcraft (2005) being of the most famous examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lineage II, as most MMO games with long lasting history, is an extremely massive game. There is incredible amount of content here. To explore most of it would take quite a lot of time, and especially if you do not plan to play intensively, it should last for quite a few weeks or even months.

Coordination of schedule with other folks is only required when actively playing within a clan. While playing solo, you are not likely to have much problems finding people for temporal parties.

That said, you will surely have most fun with any MMO when playing with a friend or two, even when played casually.

Comment: Have you ever played Lineage 2?

Comment: The official? Yes I did.

Comment: @sarmackie Oh, thanks. One or two friends I'll manage. I'm glad it doesn't have to be 20.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, Lineage after a certain point is group only.
2. The more you have, the better, depending on what you would like to achieve. If you have a small group, you will only grind forever. You need a bigger group to enjoy the other content the game offers. The maximum party size is 7, so 6 friends are required.